# Vue.js Vuetify v-file-input with required rule shows required error before a file is even selected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file-upload, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Now an error is shown immediately after the input is clicked, before any file has been selected.
This is misleading and confusing.

**QUESTION**
How to change rules to show an error only when the upload form is cancelled and no file is selected?

Code example → https://codepen.io/lisymcaydnlb/pen/mdEWPow
Image example ↓

[image: example]

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-file-input
                  label="File"
                  :rules="[v => !!v || 'File is mandatory']"
                  show-size
                  truncate-length="100"
                  append-icon="attach_file"
              ></v-file-input>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: vuetify,
})
```

Comment: Known bug: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9480. Closing bugs without fixing them is a common practice for Vuetify team. You could use vee-validate which gives you more control over validation, with `:mode`.